# Inserting in a linked list

Tags: java, arrays, linked-list

```
    public void display(ListNode head)
{
   if(head == null)
       return;
   ListNode current = head;
   while (current != null){
       System.out.print(current.data + " -->");
       current = current.next;
   }
   System.out.print(current);
   
}
   
    public void insertAfter(ListNode previous, int data)
{
    if (previous == null){
        System.out.println("The given previous node cannot be null");
        return;}
    ListNode newNode = new ListNode(data);
    newNode.next = previous.next;
    previous.next = newNode;
    }
```

---

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    ListNode head = new ListNode(10);
    ListNode second = new ListNode(8);
    ListNode third = new ListNode(1);
    ListNode fourth = new ListNode(11);

    head.next = second;
    second.next = third;
    third.next = fourth;

    System.out.println("\nAfter what digit of number in the array would you " 
            + "like to add a new number?");
    int pos = scan.nextInt();
    ListNode position = null;
    switch(pos)
    {
    case '0': position = head;break;
    case '1': position = second;break;
    case '2': position = third; break;
    case '3': position = fourth; break;
    }
    System.out.println(position);
    
    System.out.println("\nWhat number would you like to add?");
    int num3 = scan.nextInt();
    
    LL.insertAfter(position, num3);
    System.out.println();
    LL.display(head);
    }
```

---

> 10 -->8 -->1 -->11-->null
>
> After what digit of number in the array would you like to add a new number?
>
> 2
>
> null
>
> What number would you like to add?
>
> 1
>
> The given previous node cannot be null
>
> 10 -->8 -->1 -->11 -->null

---

Couldn't make the switch work appropriately, can anyone help me with this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Inserting numbers in a LinkedList using a switch case is just not the way to go. Look below for a correct way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you don't have an understanding of how LinkedLists work. You are trying to have a pointer initialized for each of the nodes, which is impossible to do for long lists. Inserting numbers in a LinkedList using a switch case is just not the way to go.

LinkedLists are made of nodes like the one described below.

```
class ListNode {
    int val;
    ListNode next;

    public ListNode(int val, ListNode next) {
        this.val = val;
        this.next = next;
    }
}
```

Say, we want to add 5 values to a LinkedList.

```
int numItems = 5;
ListNode head = null;

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

while(numItems != 0) {

    // take input from user
    int val = sc.nextInt();

    // list is currently empty
    if(head == null) 
        head = new ListNode(val, null);
    else {
        // go the last node in the list
        ListNode cur = head;
        while(cur.next != null)
            cur = cur.next;

        // cur now points to the last node in the list
        // can add new ListNode here
        cur.next = new ListNode(val, null);
    }
    numItems--;
}
```

Say, list looks like this 5 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1 -> 4 -> null

Now, the user wants to enter a number after the first 2 nodes.

```
int insertAfter = 2;
// I am assuming the list contains > `insertAfter` elements
ListNode cur = head;
while(insertAfter > 1) {
    cur = cur.next;
    insertAfter--;
}
```

`cur` now points to to the 3 in the sample linked list.

```
ListNode newNode = new ListNode(102234, cur.next);
```

A new node was created that has 2 as it's next.

```
cur.next = newNode;
```

`cur` now points to `newNode`

List now looks like 5 -> 3 -> 102234 -> 2 -> 1 -> 4 -> null

Let me know if you have any clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

To make the swich work, remove single quotes from cases e.g.:

```
switch(pos)
    {
    case 0: position = head;break;
    case 1: position = second;break;
    case 2: position = third; break;
    case 3: position = fourth; break;
    }
```

Comment: @DarshanMehta hard coding indices to insert to?! what happens when I try to add after index 4? have another variable? what about index 6? another variable, I presume?

Comment: @DebosmitRay good point. However, I am not completely aware about the purpose of this program. OP asked a specific question of `swich` not functioning and hence, I suggested fix for that only :)

Comment: @DarshanMehta Then, please mention that in your post. The post is titled 'Add a number after a appointed position of a linked list'. If someone who is a beginner reads this, s/he might think that it is acceptable to have pointers for each and every node just to enable insertion after a certain index!

Comment: This is not my post.

Comment: @DebosmitRay Which means do I need to throw an Exception to limit the range of index number?

Comment: @SamuelPeterson What if the user wants to insert a number in the 5th index? Sure, you can check to see if the index is within the total number of elements in your list. What when you have a 100 element long list and the user wants to enter a number after the 90th index? You would need 90 cases in your switch case!

Comment: @DebosmitRay Yeah I understood that but only wanted to test the use of switch somehow and see if that work well for a certain number of nodes. But thank you for pointing it out tho, that my title was kind of misleading...